# Converting a button click to require.js style coding

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm getting lost with require.js.  Define always seems to return something in the require.js sample pages.

How do i convert the following to require.js style coding?

```
$("button_1").click(function(event) {
    alert("button 1 has been clicked");
});
```

As it `returns` nothing.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a page working with the require lib and jquery included etc?

Comment: Yes, but it's local only.  For this reason, I have tried to simplfy the example,  I think if I can get the above code requirejs'ified, it should help me understand it better.

Comment: Might help to go into detail how you have your project laid out, what config options you have etc. I don't understand the "As it returns nothing" problem. If you want a super simple example, just wrap the above code in a require() call that makes jQuery one of it's deps.

Comment: the the 2 anwsers below not solve youre problem? if so can you explain abit better?

Comment: @oshirowanen take a look at the anwser below. it shows how to setup require.js whith jquery in the base nature of it. and if you think somthing is lacking do give a explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think youre missing the require part. when youre using a AMD you need to "import" youre other modules before you can use em. look at the following example it shod be enough to get you going. by using the requrejs+jquery download:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/requirejs_jquery" data-main="path/to/main.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button_1">sup</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
require(["jquery"],function($){ //import the jquery script 
  $(function(){
    $("#button_1").click(function(){
      alert("#button_1 got a click")
    })
  })
})
```

you mention Define aswell, thats when you want to declare a new module that you can later "import" to youre project. so lets expand abit and make a folder called "my" and place it next to the main script

**my/module.js**

```
define(function(){
  return {
    foo: function(){alert("bar")},
    barz: function(){return "hey from barz"}
  }
})
```

now we can simply include it in the main file (or other module for that matter) like this:

**main.js**

```
require(["jquery", "my/module"],function($, module){ //import the jquery script 
  $(function(){
    $("#button_1").click(function(){
      alert("#button_1 got a click")
      console.log(module,"sup")
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("button_1").click(function(event) {});` returns nothing because you do not specify whether you want the element's `id` or `class`.

If you want the element's `id`:

EXAMPLE:
`<input id="button_1" type="button" />`

```
$("#button_1").click(function(event) {
    alert("button 1 has been clicked");
});
```

If you want the element's `class`:

EXAMPLE:
`<input class="button_1" type="button" />`

```
$(".button_1").click(function(event) {
    alert("button 1 has been clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your question is that:
You want to get your head around require.js and AMD and want to start with a sample that's stripped down to the bare minimum.

I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kk6Tb/4/) that illustrates your button_1 example and lets you play around with the require.js behaviour by looking at the console and the inspector's network tab.

At the heart of require.js you have the main.js file where you define your load dependencies. I've chosen a simplified shim structure to define the dependencies:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {                // the shim structure controls your load dependencies
        'jquery': [],
        'sample1.amd': ['jquery'],    // the key denotes the module name, the value array lists the dependenc(y|ies)
        'sample2.amd': ['jquery']    // the key denotes the module name, the value array lists the dependenc(y|ies)
    },
    waitSeconds: 30            // maximum time to wait for the modules to load
});

require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'sample1.amd',
        'sample2.amd'
    ],
    function(
        $    // $ is the local instance of the defined module 'jquery' (see 1st plugin in dependency array above)
    ) {
        console.log("jQuery, sample1.amd.js and sample2.amd.js loaded through AMD");
    }
);
```

You will load the main.js file (and consequently, all files defined within main.js) by specifying:

```
<script src="/path-to/require-jquery.js" data-main="/path-to/main.js" ></script>
```

Your button click definition is wrapped in sample1.amd.js.
For demo purpose, I *also* wrapped the same button click definition in sample2.amd.js
That's why in the demo you will see 2 log messages in the console when you click the button.

When you inspect the load behaviour in your network tab, you can also note the positive performance impact that you may gain with require.js:
sample1.amd.js and sample2.amd.js load *in parallel* - regardless of the dependencies, require.js will always load modules as early as possible, only their execution will be queued according to their dependencies.

Here's a link to [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kk6Tb/4/). Hope that gets you started with require.js

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good explanation of how to get set up with RequireJS and jQuery [on the RequireJS site](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html). It's easiest to just download the [combined jQuery and RequireJS file](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#get). It's not strictly necessary as you should be able to just include jQuery as normal and use AMD for loading everything else, but I haven't thoroughly tested it myself. I use the combined jQuery + RequireJS file, as it's pretty simple once you get the hang of it.

In the *simplest case* for what you want to do (e.g., if you have your one main *script* that you want to run as a dependency of jQuery), all you would need is to include `require.js` in your HTML file, like so:

```
<script data-main="path/to/yourScript.js" src="path/to/require.js"></script>
```

Making sure to include your script in the data-main attribute of the script tag. Then, in `yourScript.js`, you would wrap your code like so:

```
/* yourScript.js */
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    // Use jQuery normally.
    $("#button_1").click(function(event) {
        alert("button 1 has been clicked");
    });        
});
```

Now, this is the simplest, imperative example and doesn't really use the AMD paradigm or dynamic dependencies at all. But it serves as a rough, working example to start from. Now, if you wanted to wrap up your `$("button_1").click` function in an AMD module, you could make a `button1.js` file and wrap it up in a `define()` call:

```
/* button1.js */
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    // The following code will be run when this module is loaded.
    $("#button_1").click(function(event) {
         alert("button 1 has been clicked");
    });
    return {name: "button1 module!"}; 
    // Above, I'm just illustrating that AMD modules usually 
    // return an object or a function to pass to the anonymous 
    // function that's called when they're loaded by a dependency.
});

/* yourScript.js */
require(['jquery', 'button1'], function($, button1) {
    alert(button1.name); // This will alert with "button1 module"
});
```

The take-home point is that both `define()` and `require()` take an array of dependencies (which are just .js filenames, optionally without the .js), and a function as parameters. They will then execute the code found in those files, passing the returned value as arguments to their function paramater. This is a little bit of an oversimplification of the loading and dependency scheme, but it should be enough to get you started.

I've written up the live, working example here: https://c9.io/aphazel/requirejs-simple-example

P.S., you probably wanted to use `$('#button_1')` or `$('.button_1')` :)